# Digi Pro Pen Tablet 640 Drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics-tablet

I have a Digi Pro Pen Tablet 640. I used to use it with windows. But my windows sucked so I switched to Ubuntu. Is there a way to install the drivers into Ubuntu? There is no Ubuntu drivers provided so I was going to try this windows wireless drivers program. But I don't know how to use it. Can anyone help me? I have the windows drivers though!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92636/how-do-i-get-a-digipro-wp8060-tablet-working

Comment: Have you looked at: (wiki) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TabletSetupWizardpen ?